# "System gesture gate timed" out with UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a main view controller (`UICollectionViewController`) and the cells consist of a `UIImageView`, a `UILabel` and a `UITableView`.

Something like this

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                    |
| +-------------Cell-------------+  +-------------Cell-------------+ |
| |                              |  |                              | |
| | +-------+                    |  | +-------+                    | |
| | | Image |       Label        |  | | Image |       Label        | |
| | +-------+                    |  | +-------+                    | |
| |                              |  |                              | |
| | +--------------------------+ |  | +--------------------------+ | |
| | |                          | |  | |                          | | |
| | | TableView                | |  | | TableView                | | |
| | |                          | |  | |                          | | |
| | +--------------------------+ |  | +--------------------------+ | |
| +------------------------------+  +------------------------------+ |
:                                                                    :
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In the `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, I add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the image view:

```swift
    @IBOutlet private weak var imageView: UIImageView! {
        didSet {
            let gr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.settingsButtonTouched))
            imageView.gestureRecognizers?.append(gr)
        }
    }
```

So far so good.
If I now tap on the image view, the action is not triggered, but only the following text appears in the log:

```
[SystemGestureGate] <0x129f2ab10> Gesture: System gesture gate timed out.
```

I only found references to SwiftUI, but I don't use that in this app.
Does anyone have any idea what is causing this and more importantly how to solve it?

Comment: I don't think adding that gesture recognizer in didSet is a good idea. I think you should add them elsewhere like in the cell's init method.

Answer (score -2):

Well,
I should have used

```swift
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gr)
```

instead of

```swift
imageView.gestureRecognizers?.append(gr)
```

since `imageView.gestureRecognizers` is nil.
‍♂️

(The message `System gesture gate timed out` still appears, but it wasn't the reason the gesture recognizer didn't work. )